# Scanning Evernote and sharing by email

Tags: evernote, document-scanner

Is it possible to use the Android app [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote&hl=en) to scan several images, then save them as a single PDF, and share the PDF by email, without requiring the recipient to have an Evernote account?

I managed to scan several images, and save them as a single PDF, but when I email it Evernote requires the recipient to have an Evernote account:

[image]

I don't have this issue when I use [Evernote Scannable](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote-scannable/id883338188?mt=8) on iOS 9.

Comment: As of now Scannable for Android is not available([only for iOS](https://evernote.com/products)). And Evernote and Scannable are different apps released by Evernote Corporation. Read [this comment](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2015/01/08/scannable-new-mobile-scanning-app-evernote/#comment-1707253) from this Scannable Team, _So for now, the short answer to “When will Scannable come to Android?” is still “We don’t know yet.” ._ Also, check out this app [PDF Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grymala.photoscannerpdftrial) if it helps your case.

Comment: Also, check this app [Droid Scan Pro PDF](https://appcenter.evernote.com/app/droid-scan/android) _Droid Scan turns your Android phone into a pocket document scanner. It will convert any snapshot into a highly readable JPEG or PDF by fixing geometry, contrast, and color. Record white boards, business cards, receipts and a lot more._

Comment: @Lucky Thanks, I'm getting lost with all these Evernote products. i'll definitely try Droid Scan Pro PDF!

Comment: As mentioned in the Play Store description, _Please try the free version first ([Droid Scan Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trans_code.android.droidscanlite)) to make sure this app is compatible with your device_.